# Unable to link SDL2 in kotlin native

Tags: kotlin, sdl-2, kotlin-native

I am unable to link a Kotlin-native binary with SDL2. Namely undefined references.

I come from a c/c++/other native languages background. So I know exactly what it is failing to do, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I'm on Linux and first trying to get it working for such. Then adapt it to other platforms later.

The sources have been adapted from https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/kotlin-native/samples/tetris

###### libsdl.def:

```
headers = SDL.h stdlib.h time.h
entryPoint = SDL_main

headerFilter = SDL* stdlib.h time.h

compilerOpts = -D_POSIX_SOURCE
compilerOpts.linux = -I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
linkerOpts.linux = -L/usr/lib -pthread -lSDL2 -lm -ldl
```

###### build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "me.ketanr"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    nativeTarget.apply {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"

                linkerOpts("-L/usr/lib", "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", "-lSDL2", "-lpthread", "-ldl", "-lm")
            }
        }

        // compilations.getByName("main") {
        //     cinterops {
        //         val libsdl by creating {
        //             includeDirs("/usr/include", "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu", "/usr/include/SDL2")
        //         }
        //     }
        // }
        compilations["main"].cinterops {
            val libsdl by creating {
                includeDirs("/usr/include", "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu", "/usr/include/SDL2")
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}
```

###### error log:

```
> Task :linkDebugExecutableNative FAILED
e: /home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.gold invocation reported errors

The /home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.gold command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/crti.o
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/8.3.0/crtbegin.o
/tmp/konan_temp6274769675767169924/result.o
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib64/libpthread.so.0
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libdl.so
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libm.so
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libm.so
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libdl.so
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_personality.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(del_op.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(si_class_type_info.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_alloc.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_exception.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_ptr.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(class_type_info.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(del_ops.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_catch.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_throw.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(guard.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_terminate.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_term_handler.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(vterminate.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_call.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_unex_handler.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(list.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(tree.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(chrono.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(hashtable_c++0x.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(tinfo.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_type.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(pure.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.a(guard_error.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libdl.so
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libm.so
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib64/libpthread.so.0
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/8.3.0/libgcc.a(cpuinfo.o)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib64/libc.so.6
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS)
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/8.3.0/crtend.o
/home/ketanr/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/crtn.o
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'powf', version 'GLIBC_2.27'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'exp', version 'GLIBC_2.29'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'fstat', version 'GLIBC_2.33'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_sigmask', version 'GLIBC_2.32'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'dlerror', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_once', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_setspecific', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_key_create', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_detach', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_join', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_getspecific', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'sem_trywait', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_mutexattr_settype', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'dlopen', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'sem_timedwait', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'sem_post', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_attr_setstacksize', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'sem_init', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'expf', version 'GLIBC_2.27'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_create', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'log', version 'GLIBC_2.29'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_mutexattr_init', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'logf', version 'GLIBC_2.27'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'sem_wait', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'sem_getvalue', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'sem_destroy', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'dlclose', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'dlsym', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pow', version 'GLIBC_2.29'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_mutex_trylock', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/libSDL2.so: error: undefined reference to 'stat', version 'GLIBC_2.33'

Execution failed for task ':linkDebugExecutableNative'.
> Compilation finished with errors

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

###### `uname -a`:

> `Linux fujitsu-endeavour 5.16.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 16 Feb 2022 19:35:18 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

###### `cat /etc/*-release`:

```
Arch Linux release
DISTRIB_ID=EndeavourOS
DISTRIB_RELEASE="rolling"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="EndeavourOS Linux"
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rolling
NAME=EndeavourOS
PRETTY_NAME=EndeavourOS
ID=endeavouros
ID_LIKE=arch
BUILD_ID=2021.11.30
ANSI_COLOR="38;2;23;147;209"
HOME_URL='https://endeavouros.com'
DOCUMENTATION_URL='https://forum.endeavouros.com/c/Arch-based-related-questions/bug-reports'
SUPPORT_URL='https://forum.endeavouros.com'
BUG_REPORT_URL='https://forum.endeavouros.com/c/arch-based-related-questions/bug-reports'
LOGO=endeavouros
```

Comment: Your system seems to be inconsistent: your shared libraries (e.g. libSDL2.so a libc.so) are incompatible. Also you have installed components like gcc into your HOME-directory which is a big no-no.

Comment: it is kotlin native that is installing gcc there. If I delete it, the `.konan` folder, the build process just redownloads it and continues to return the same error. Do you know of a solution to change that?

Comment: As start: what is the name and exact version of your OS? (if unsure, try `cat /etc/*release`)

Comment: Added info to post

Comment: You shoul install Kotlin from your distribution, guess it would be `sudo pacman -S kotlin` or sg like this.

Comment: That, unfortunately, changed nothing, Gradle still downloads everything to the `.konan` folder and fails all the same.

Comment: Could you first try to compile and run some simple examples without Gradle (or any "helping program")?

Comment: Are you aware of how java/kotlin projects work? Thats like asking me to compile rust without cargo or like manually typing in each command listed in a make file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default kotlin native uses its own minimal toolchain via konan with a gcc at version 8.3.0, glibc at 2.19, and the Linux kernel at 4.9.

The recommended way would probably be:

- Set up a Docker image of an older Linux distro with the same/similar specifications to the konan toolchain, at the very least matching the glibc version.
- Install SDL2 by package manager so that you now have a version of SDL linked against the version of glibc konan uses.
- Build the executable in the Docker container.

Setting up a build system with this old of a glibc version seems improbable because even Debian Stretch doesn't have one quite that old. (2.24) I think the below hacking around to use system libraries might have better luck being used in the Docker container than trying to duplicate the konan toolchain.

My way of "fixing" this was to override some of the values konan uses in my Gradle build. You can see all of the properties and their default values at kotlin-native/konan/konan.properties in the kotlin-native sources which may be required beyond just initializing SDL2 as that was my only goal with the following and more problems might occur later.

Keep in mind this is breaking basically every rule they gave on how to use their software that I saw while looking through the bug reports that gave me this information, so anything can break at any time.

To get my application using SDL2 to build I did the following:

**build.gradle.kts**: I overrode the targetSysRoot and libGcc konan properties with my own system. Version for libGcc is set to null here because I have a bash script that replaces this line with my currently installed version since on a rolling release this can change often. It would also be helpful when running on an older system to get better backwards compatibility for release.

```kotlin
    linuxX64 {
        compilations.getByName("main") {
            cinterops {
                val sdl by creating
            }
        }
        binaries {
            executable {
                val sysRoot = "/"
                val libGccVersion = null
                val libGcc = "/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/$libGccVersion"
                val overriddenProperties = "targetSysRoot.linux_x64=$sysRoot;libGcc.linux_x64=$libGcc"
                freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
                    "-Xoverride-konan-properties=${overriddenProperties}"
                )
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }
```

**replaceLibGccVersion.sh**: This is the bash file I'm currently using to easily update the libGcc version in `build.gradle.kts` when needed.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

buildFile="../build.gradle.kts"
test -f "$buildFile" || `echo "Build file $buildFile not found. Exiting..." && exit`
varDef="val libGccVersion = "
gccVersion="`ls /lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/`"
newVersion="$varDef\"$gccVersion\""
currentVersion=`grep "$varDef" "$buildFile"`
currentVersion=${currentVersion#"${currentVersion%%[![:space:]]*}"}
if [ "$newVersion" != "$currentVersion" ]
then
  echo "Replacing $currentVersion with $newVersion in $buildFile"
  sed -i "s/^\(\s*\)$varDef.*$/\1$newVersion/" "$buildFile"
else
  echo "$buildFile already has the current libGcc version set"
fi
```

**sdl.def**: I simplified because if we're using the local system toolchain, there's no reason to fear mixing between the local system and the build toolchain's header files

```
headers = SDL2/SDL.h
entryPoint = SDL_main

compilerOpts.linux = -I/usr/include
linkerOpts.linux = -lSDL2
```

With this I was able to build the usual SDL Hello World window to work.

**Main.kt**

```kotlin
import cnames.structs.SDL_Window
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import sdl.*

private const val SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
private const val SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480

fun main() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        throw Error("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: ${SDL_GetError()}")
    }

    val window: CPointer<SDL_Window> = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Hello, world!",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED.toInt(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED.toInt(),
        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    ) ?: throw Error("SDL could not create window! SDL_Error: ${SDL_GetError()}")

    val surface: CPointer<SDL_Surface>? = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)
    SDL_FillRect(surface, null, SDL_MapRGB(surface?.pointed?.format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF))
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window)
    SDL_Delay(2000)
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window)
    SDL_Quit()
}
```